# Existence of a Lie algebra element orthogonal to the adjoint orbit of another element

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, oc.optimization-and-control

Consider a compact, semi-simple, connected Lie group $G$ and its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Denote the Killing form by $K$.

Given a single $A \in \mathfrak{g}$ when (i.e. which groups and which $A$) can one find a $B \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that:

$K(B, Ad_{g}(A)) = 0$ $\ \ \forall g \in G$

The case of $SU(n)$ is particularly important. I believe that I've shown it to never be possible for $SU(2)$.

Comment: Ok, let me extend my question. If $g_t$ is an arbitrary smooth curve on $G$ then when (i.e. for which curves) can we find a $B$ s.t. $K(B, Ad_{g_t}(A)) = 0$.

Comment: The curve must have $g_0 = e$ in fact.

Answer (score 2):

If your group is *simple* the adjoint representation is irreducible, so a (nonzero) orbit always spans $\mathfrak g$ and hence will not be contained in $B^\perp$ for any (nonzero) $B$. If $G$ is only semi-simple, you get $G(A)\subset B^\perp$ by taking $A$ and $B$ in different simple factors.

(For your extended question: let's again take $G$ simple and $A\ne0$. As the orbit $G(A)$ spans $\mathfrak g$, you can draw on it a curve $g_t(A)$ that still spans, hence is not in $B^\perp$ for any nonzero $B$. On the other hand, you may of course first fix some $B\in A^\perp$ and then draw, in $B^\perp\cap G(A)$, a curve having your desired property.)

Comment: That's very clear thanks. Is there a criterion that can be deduced for which curves, or at least some non trivial curves, which $Ad_{g_t}(A)$ will fail to span the Lie algebra? In fact this issue only matters if $G$ is simple so that's the only case I care about.

Comment: If you are at liberty to draw the curve $\{g_t\}$ at will, then I sketched a way. If you *already* have the curve and need to decide whether $\{g_t(A)\}$ spans, we might need to know more on how your curve is given.

Comment: I'm interested in finding a condition for the curve to have $\{g_t(A)\}$ spanning, so the curve is not given. The actual curves I'm interested in are solution to $\frac{d g_t}{dt} = (a + w(t)b)g_t$ for some smooth function $w(t)$. Ultimately I'm hoping for a condition on the function $w$.

Comment: Here $a,b$ are some given elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\{a,b\}_{L.A.} = \mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: Sounds like a control theory problem (à la [this](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=331185)) that you might need to post as such...